# Assembly MIPS: Reverse printing two strings

Tags: assembly, mips

Lets say that you type a name first and a surname last and you want the program to print the surname first and then the name.

f.e.

> Gabe
>
> Newell

Newell

Gabe

Ι tried to make just that:

```
.data  
first: .word
second: .word

.text
.globl main 
main: 

li       $v0, 8 
la       $a0, first
la   $a1, 20 
syscall

move     $s1, $a0

la       $a0, second
la   $a1, 20 
syscall

li   $v0, 4
la       $a0, second
syscall
     
move     $a0, $s1

la       $a0, 0($s1)
syscall
```

li       $v0, 10
syscall

but at the output it gives me:
newell
newell

So, what it the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set aside enough space for the names; `.word` only sets aside enough for an integer (2 or 4 bytes, probably the latter).

Use `.space` instead.

Then, to print the first name, you need to load the address of `first` into `$a0` before making the `syscall`; `$s1` does not have the value you think it does.

Comment: i replace it with "first: .space 20" and
"second: .space 20" but it still gives the surname twice instead of the surname followed by the name